# Why won't my autoscan scan back and forth?

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a project with a microchip max32 board in C. I need help with a small portion. Here's the portion I'm working on:

```
if (motor_step == 0){

    auto_direction = 1;


    }

if (motor_step == step_max){

    auto_direction = 0;

    }

if(auto_direction == 0){

    indexM = indexM + 1;

    motor_step++;

    }

if(auto_direction == 1) {

    indexM = indexM - 1;

    motor_step--;

    }
```

Basically my teacher gave us most of the code to work with and told us to figure out the auto-scan portion. If you scroll down, you will see where I need to input my own code. On the project, we control the motor that is holding a laser pointer. The auto-scan is basically supposed to scan up and down and go on continuously. After 16 steps the motor should stop and go the opposite direction(+ for up and - for down.) The problem that I'm having is that when I run my code, the auto-scan is not stopping. If we run the code, the laser will either continue to scan upwards or downwards(depending on what it was doing the last time it turned on) but doesn't stop and do the opposite after 16 steps.

Thanks in advance and hope I was somewhat clear. Towards the end is where you will see what code I'm changing. Here is the remainder of my code for reference:

```
// EX03_Starter_StepperMotorControl_REVB
// 10-3-2013
//------------------------------------------------
// Status:
//   * REVB Starter Template created
//------------------------------------------------                                 
// Author:            Coach 
// Target Hardware:       Digilent chipKITMax32 board + Basic I/O Board
// Development Platform:  mpide-0023-windows-20120903
//---------------------------------------------------
// Objective: Provide control logic for stepper motor control
//      *** This code can be adapted for chipKITMax32 or Arduino Nano

// Stepper Motor Control Logic:
// ============================

//  Stepper Motor Driver keep track of indexM pointing to stepper Motor Drive Table:
//          IndexM  D3 D2 D1 D0  Hex Value
//          =====   == == == ==  =========
//           0       0  0  0  1      1
//           1       0  1  0  0      4
//           2       0  0  1  0      2
//           3   1  0  0  0      8

//  * Wraps around logic is provided by : indexM = indexM & 3
//  * To move clockwise, indexM = indexM + 1
//  * To move counter clockwise, indexM = indexM - 1
//----------------------------------------
//   I/O Assignments:
//   ===============
//   SW1: Run (SW1 = 0: Stop / SW1 = 1: Run)
//   SW2: Direction (SW2= 0: Clockwise/ SW2 = 1: CounterClockWise)
//   SW3: Autoscan (SW3 = 0: Manual / SW3 = 1: Autoscan )
//   SW4: Timing Control (SW4 = 0: Development, SW4=1: Real)

//   LD1: Run Indicator
//   LD2: Direction Indicator
//   LD3: spare
//   LD4: spare

//   Simulation:
//   LD5: Motor Coil D0
//   LD6: Motor Coil D1
//   LD7: Motor Coil D2
//   LD8: Motor Coil D3

//  Physical Motor Drive:
//   MotorCoil_0 : pin0
//   MotorCoil_1 : pin1
//   MotorCoil_2 : pin2
//   MotorCoil_3 : pin3
//------------------------------------------
//   Functional requirements:
//   ======================= 
//   0. Reflect SW1,SW2,SW3,SW4 to LD1,LD2,LD3,LD4

//   1. When the system is not running (Run = 0), disable all outputs
//   2. When the system is running (Run = 1), read Direction switch
//     2.1 If Direction ==0, run motor clockwise
//     2.2 If Direction ==1, run motor counter clockwise

//   3. Auto scan feature:(Note: to be designed & coded by you)
//       SW3: Autoscan (SW3 = 0: Manual / SW3 = 1: Autoscan )
//       When in manual mode, execute function 2.1 & 2.2 
//       When in autoscan mode: stepper motor moves up 16 steps then moves down 16 steps, repeats continuously  

//   4. Timing Control (SW4) input:
//      4.1 When in Development mode (SW4 == 0): motorTime = 500 (ms)
//      4.2 When in Real mode (SW4 == 1): motorTime = 10 (ms)
// =======================================================
// Tasks:

// 0. Review "How Stepper Motor Works" power point

// 1. Read & understand this sample code

// 2. Run & verify that it works as written

// 3. *** Design your Autoscan logic using Flow Chart, review with Coach

// 4. *** Add Code for Your Design prescribed in item 3 above

// 5. Verify your code works as prescribed, troubleshoot & fix it as required

// 6. *** Provide optical report to Coach

// 7. *** Verify at System Bench Test with Laser pointer Assembly
//==========================================================================

// set pin numbers:
const int BTN1 = 4;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int BTN2 = 78;    //***** Note: label on the board is for Uno32, this is MAX32, see MAX32 Reference Manual

const int ledPin =  13;      // System Operational LED
const int LD1 =  70;     //***** Note: label on the board is for Uno32, this is MAX32, see MAX32 Reference Manual
const int LD2 =  71;     // ******** LD pins are corrected here.

const int LD3 =  72;
const int LD4 =  73;
const int LD5 =  74;
const int LD6 =  75;
const int LD7 =  76;
const int LD8 =  77;


const int SW1 = 2;
const int SW2 = 7;
const int SW3 = 8;
const int SW4 = 79;     //***** Note: label on the I/O board is 35 for uno32 only

// variables:
int BTN1_state = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int SW1_state = 0; 
int SW2_state = 0; 
int SW3_state = 0; 
int SW4_state = 0; 

int motorTime = 1000;   // 1000 ms = 1s
// Initial Stepper Motor Coil pattern
int indexM =0;
int step_max = 16;
int motor_step = 0;
int auto_direction = 0;


void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(LD1, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(LD2, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(LD3, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(LD4, OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(LD5, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(LD6, OUTPUT);    
  pinMode(LD7, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(LD8, OUTPUT);     

  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(BTN1, INPUT);  

  // initialize switches as inputs:
   pinMode(SW1, INPUT);  
   pinMode(SW2, INPUT);
   pinMode(SW3, INPUT);
   pinMode(SW4, INPUT); 

  // Turn OFF all LEDs
 digitalWrite(LD1, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD2, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD3, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD4, LOW);  

    // Initial Stepper Motor Coil pattern
 digitalWrite(LD5, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD6, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD7, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD8, LOW); 

} // end setup()

void loop(){
  // System Operation LED ON:
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
     delay(10);                  // wait for x ms
  //----------------------------------------------  

  // read switches inputs:
  SW1_state = digitalRead(SW1);
  SW2_state = digitalRead(SW2); 
  SW3_state = digitalRead(SW3);
  SW4_state = digitalRead(SW4); 

// Echo switches to LED Indicators:
  if (SW1_state == HIGH) {digitalWrite(LD1, HIGH);  }
  if (SW1_state == LOW) {digitalWrite(LD1, LOW);  }

  if (SW2_state == HIGH) {digitalWrite(LD2, HIGH);  }
  if (SW2_state == LOW) {digitalWrite(LD2, LOW);  }

  if (SW3_state == HIGH) {digitalWrite(LD3, HIGH);  }
  if (SW3_state == LOW) {digitalWrite(LD3, LOW);  }

  if (SW4_state == HIGH) {digitalWrite(LD4, HIGH);  }
  if (SW4_state == LOW) {digitalWrite(LD4, LOW);  }


// Arm Logic: 
if (SW1_state == LOW) {
  // system NOT running:
   digitalWrite(LD5, LOW); 
   digitalWrite(LD6, LOW); 
   digitalWrite(LD7, LOW); 
   digitalWrite(LD8, LOW); 

} // end if (SW1_State == LOW)
//==============================

if (SW1_state == HIGH) {     // system is running

if (SW3_state == LOW)   // manual mode
{
// Direction control:  
// 2.1 If Direction ==0, run motor clockwise
 if (SW2_state == LOW) {indexM = indexM + 1;  }

// 2.2 If Direction ==1, run motor counter clockwise 
 if (SW2_state == HIGH) {indexM = indexM - 1;  }
} // end if (SW3_state == LOW)

if (SW3_state == HIGH)   // autoscan mode
{

  // *** Add your Autoscan codes here ***       <---------This is where my code goes.

} // end if (SW3_state == HIGH) 

// Timing Control / Speed select processing:
if (SW4_state == LOW)   // Development (slow)
  {
  motorTime = 500;     // unit in ms
  } 
if (SW4_state == HIGH)  // Running real motor (fast)
  {
  motorTime = 10;       // unit in ms
  } 

//=========== Stepper Motor Driver ========  

indexM = indexM & 3;  // wraps-around logic
switch (indexM)
{
case 0:

 digitalWrite(LD5, HIGH); 
 digitalWrite(LD6, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD7, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD8, LOW); 

    break;

case 1:

 digitalWrite(LD5, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD6, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD7, HIGH); 
 digitalWrite(LD8, LOW); 

    break;
case 2:
 digitalWrite(LD5, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD6, HIGH); 
 digitalWrite(LD7, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD8, LOW); 

    break;

case 3:
 digitalWrite(LD5, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD6, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD7, LOW); 
 digitalWrite(LD8, HIGH); 

    break;

} // End Switch (indexM)

} // end if (SW1_state == HIGH)

  //------------------------------------
   // System Operation LED OFF:
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); 
     delay(motorTime);           // wait for motorTime ms 

} // end loop
//=============================
```

So far this is what I have come up with:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the last 2 `if` statements; `if (auto_direction = 0)` and `if (auto_direction = 1)` will set `auto_direction` to 0 or 1, not compare against it. You need to use `==` like you did in the first 2 `if` statments.

Comment: Am i going to need to change the portion in the first two as well. I'm talking about the statements inside top 2. the auto_direction = 1; and the auto_direction =0;

Comment: Does everything else beside the == look okay? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hmm ... the posted code doesn't have the error. I suspect that the OP edited it (a no-no) within SO's time window that doesn't show edits (such a misfeature ... I'm amazed they haven't gotten rid of that by now).